# How to fix "InvalidInput 400: Record name {} is not valid for hosted zone" on AWS?

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-web-services

I'm migrating a site currently hosted on github pages to AWS.

The site in question is on an aws instance, with an elastic ip of http://13.40.0.39/.  The elastic IP does correctly show the site.

I want the domain [www.whitewaterwriters.com](http://www.whitewaterwriters.com) to show the site.  I created a hosted zone in root 53.

[image]

I changed the nameservers at my domain provider (qiq) and confirmed it later with whois: they have correctly changed. As per the screenshot I created a record to go to the correct IP address.

However, when I access the site I get "Hmm, We're having trouble finding that site' and using the Dig command I get server fail.

I tried 'test record' in AWS and got:

[image]

> Error occurred
> Bad request.
> (InvalidInput 400: Record name 'https://www.whitewaterwriters.com/' is not valid for hosted zone: https\072\057\057www.whitewaterwriters.com\057.)

My question is: what causes this particualar error in AWS (which *seems* not to currently return any SE results)? and more generally, what would be the next step for debugging dns issues in AWS.

Comment: Hang on - it appears to be that I shouldn't have put the http:// in the hosted zone - testing with another hosted zone right now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that's the error you get if you put the full 'https://www.serverfault.com/' into the hosted zone name rather than 'serverfault.com'.  Now fixed.

Answer (score 0):

DNS is a protocol that resolves names into IP's broadly speaking. It generally contains records of the type `foo.example.com` is at `192.0.2.3`. You should *never* include protocol and/or complete URI in DNS.

`http` is the protocol, whilst `www.whitewaterwriters.com` is the hostname in this case.

Domain names are used for other purposes than web browsing, such as e-mail, ssh or any other IP protocols. In addition, DNS may contain different types of records, such as CNAME pointers, MX records and so forth.